# Properly coding a constructor

Tags: excel, vba, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement a Model-View-Presenter Userinterface in VBA excel. In order to do this I have been writing different Model classes. Here an Example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TModel
    FilterCol As Collection
    N As Integer
End Type

Private this As TModel

Public Property Get FilterCol() As Collection
    Set FilterCol = this.FilterCol
End Property
Public Property Let FilterCol(ByVal value As Collection)
    Set this.FilterCol = value
End Property

Public Property Get N() As Integer
    Set N = this.N
End Property
Public Property Let N(ByVal value As Integer)
    Set this.N = value
End Property
```

This class called "FilterModel" is a collection of MSFormObjects. In order to use the collection properly I need to **new** it. So the code where I use it would look a little like this:

```
Sub testFilter()
Dim Filterm As FilterModel
Dim DefaultFilterLine As New FilterLine

Set Filterm = New FilterModel
Filterm.FilterCol = New Collection

'Set DefaultFilter
Filterm.FilterCol.Add DefaultFilterLine

'DoStuff
With New frmFilter
    Set .Model = Filterm
    .Show
End With
End Sub
```

If I don't **new** the Property FilterCol before I add something, in this case the defaultfilter, it doesn't work. So here is my Question:

Is there a way to overwrite the new statement for my new class in order to have it also new up the collection FilterCol. My research got me as far as I now know that this would be called a constructor.

**But how would one properly implement a constructor for a VBA class?**

Somthing like:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set this.FilterCol = New Collection
N = 0
End Sub
```

If I do this then I get an error in the "Property Let N(Byval Value as integer)" Line. The error message reads "object required".

Comment: You need to initialize the backing fields, not the properties: `this.N = 0`.

Comment: If there is no specific reason for encapsulating things in the TModel type I would remove it, it seems to add an unnecessary layer of complexity - N & FilterCol can be fields of the class

Comment: `Set N = this.N` should be `N = this.N` as `N` is not a *set*able reference type its an int.

Comment: @AlexK. I know, the models are complexer as this but as a minimal working example it does the job of explaining my question.

Comment: @comintern Put this as an answer. Solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: As an additional idea - you may consider using a factory pattern as a function, returning a new object. There, you may put also variables, if needed. Something like `Public Function BuildFilterModel(args) As FilterModel`. Then assign it to a variable with `Set var = BuildFilterModel(args)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. I suggest going through the code line-by-line using F8 to understand what is happening there. `Debug.print` prints values into the Immediate window.

Here is the `FilterModel` class:

```
'''   FilterModel class
Option Explicit

Private pFilterCol As Collection
Private pN As Integer

Public Property Get FilterCol() As Collection
    Set FilterCol = pFilterCol
End Property

Public Property Let FilterCol(ByVal value As Collection)
    Set pFilterCol = value
End Property

Public Property Get N() As Integer
    N = pN
End Property

Public Property Let N(ByVal value As Integer)
    pN = value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pFilterCol = New Collection
    pN = 0
End Sub
```

and here is module code to test it:

```
'''   random module
Option Explicit

Sub testFilter()

    Dim Filterm As FilterModel

    Set Filterm = New FilterModel
    Filterm.FilterCol = New Collection

    '''   default values (specified in Class_Initialize())
    Debug.Print Filterm.N
    Debug.Print Filterm.FilterCol.Count

    '''   set the values through Property Let
    Filterm.FilterCol.Add "whatever"
    Filterm.FilterCol.Add "whenever"
    Filterm.N = 6

    '''   print the new values (through Property Get)
    Debug.Print Filterm.N
    Debug.Print Filterm.FilterCol.Count
    Debug.Print Filterm.FilterCol(1)
    Debug.Print Filterm.FilterCol(2)

End Sub
```